# last_value() and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the recordset:

```
lvl | root_id | id
 1  |   3000  | 5000
 2  |   3000  | 5100
 2  |   3000  | 5110
 3  |   3000  | 5200
```

I need to group data by `root_id` filed and get the value of `id` for each `root_id` with maximum value of `lvl`:

```
  root_id | id 
    3000  | 5200
```

Something like:

```
SELECT root_id, last_value(id) over (partition by root_id order by last lvl)
FROM t
GROUP BY root_id;
```

But I get the error:

> Column t.id must appear in the GROUPO BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT root_id , id 
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by root_id order by lvl desc) rn
    FROM t
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/73182a/5/0)**:

```
| root_id |   id |
|---------|------|
|    3000 | 5200 |
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (root_id) root_id, id
FROM t
ORDER BY root_id, lvl DESC, id DESC
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dda2215134e99b9b10b4b865deefb60c)**